# Does SharePoint online has a desktop app similar to MS Teams desktop app?

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration, app, microsoft-teams

In MS Teams we can access the Teams using the MS Teams desktop app, but my question is if SharePoint online has a desktop app similar to MS Teams desktop app?

So users can access the SharePoint sites using the desktop app installed inside their windows PCs?

**EDIT:-**

I have windows 10 machine, and i get the app from this link https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/sharepoint/9nblggh510hb?activetab=pivot:overviewtab

and now it showed me that i own the app, as follow:-

[image]

but i can not find any sharepoint app inside my windows 10. so how i can have SharePoint app inside my windows 10 laptop?

Comment: It's probably showing that the _account_ that you are logged in to when you access that page has downloaded the SharePoint mobile app, not necessarily that the SharePoint mobile app is on the _device_ that you are accessing that page from.

Comment: @DylanCristy ok so the question is if we can have sharepoint desktop app inside our windows Pc?

Comment: I think Ganesh Sanap answered that - there is no desktop app for SharePoint.

Comment: @DylanCristy but what does this app @ https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/sharepoint/9nblggh510hb?activetab=pivot:overviewtab refer to?

Comment: The _mobile_ app.  The first line of the description says "Get your intranet in your pocket with the SharePoint mobile app."  It is meant for mobile devices, not desktop/laptop PCs.

Answer (score 2):

**No**, there is no desktop app for SharePoint online.

However there is mobile app for SharePoint.

**Related SharePoint UserVoice**: [SharePoint Desktop App](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/32482771-sharepoint-desktop-app)

Comment: can i install the mobile app inside windows PC?

Comment: Not sure completely, but check [this](https://www.windowslatest.com/2016/10/17/sharepoint-app-now-available-download-windows-10-pc/) if works.

Comment: can you see my edit please?

Comment: That is mobile app for SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

There is no desktop app for SharePoint online but you can use Onedrive and sync sharepoint files in there if you're using Office365. Please refer to below link for details:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sync-sharepoint-files-with-the-onedrive-sync-client-groove-exe-59b1de2b-519e-4d3a-8f45-51647cf291cd